# What does existing and new data mean exactly?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Consider the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()",
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
    }
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, data represents data before the attempted operation and newData represents data after the attempted operation.

So, consider `foo` contains the following strings. Hence `data` is

```
"foo":{
"Jellybean",
"Kitkat",
"Lollipop",
}
```

If an add operation is made, the `newData` is

```
"foo":{
"Jellybean",
"Kitkat",
"Lollipop",
"Marshmallow",
}
```

If a delete operation is made, the `newData` is

```
"foo":{
"Jellybean",
"Kitkat",
}
```

If an update operation is made, the `newData` is

```
"foo":{
"Jellybean",
"Kitkat",
"Nougat",
}
```

I'm not able to figure out how `".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"` becomes true in the first two cases but not in the third case. Can you give a clear view of what `data` and `newData` signifies and how it disallows an update request according to this rule?

Answer (score 0):

The "data" is always the data in the database.

```
In a Update ==>  "newData" is the combinated result after the update. 
In a Insert ==>  "newData" is the data being introduced.
```

In a update the data exists in the database, and the newData (combined result) exists too:

```
!data.exists() = false 
!newData.exists() = false
```

In a delete operation the newData is empty:

```
!data.exists() = false 
!newData.exists() = true
```

If you are trying do an update in /foo the methods data and newData in rules return this:

```
data = "foo":{
 "Jellybean",
 "Kitkat",
 "Lollipop",
 }

newData = "foo":{
 "Jellybean",
 "Kitkat",
 "Lollipop",
 "Marshmallow",
}
```

newData is how the element "foo" will be in the database after the update.

Comment: How is newData.exists() true in case of an update? Can you explain me with the above examples?

Comment: newData is how the element "foo" will be in the database after the update, in a update is always true, check the updated answer.

Comment: Isn't the example you've given an addition of new data and not an update?

Comment: You are confusing the states, you make an update to a route /foo, adding or removing Strings. You update the data in "foo" with other data.